# Using php and POST on a form, but request_method says it is a GET

Tags: php, post, get

So I have this form that I am submitting to a php script that echos $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']. I do not know why, but even though I specify the POST method in the form, it always echoes GET.  Why is this? What am I doing wrong?

```
<form action="location.php" method="POST">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>name</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>address</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="address"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>lat</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="lat"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>lng</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="lng"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>user</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="user"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>type</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="type"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>method</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="methoda"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td><input type="submit" name="submit"></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Is it a typo or did you forget to close your `<table>` with a `</table>`?

Comment: I did forget to, updated the code, and still have the same problem.

Comment: Without being very familiar with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`, I would like to ask you to try to call either `echo("<pre>GET: ".print_r($_GET, true)."</pre>");`, or `echo("<pre>POST: ".print_r($_POST, true)."</pre>");`, in the location.php file, to display the GET and POST arrays. Try with some values.

Comment: Use HTTPfox or Firebug to monitor the client-server communications. I'm guessing that something's forcing a redirect, so you'd see the POST go out, come back as a redirect, then you hit the same url again as a GET. Possibly a bad mod_rewrite rule.

Comment: Thanks. I found the problem.  In my location.php, I had header("Content-Type: text/xml"); I am trying to return an xml document, and apparently it didnt like that. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as I have spent countless hours trying to fix a bug related to the "REQUST_METHOD" being wrong in PHP and not finding anything helpful online, this is my report on the issue: Chrome seems to have a bug in the Version 30.0.1599.101

my jquery test code was:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '../Server/test.php',
  data: {data:"data"}
});
$.ajax({
  type: "PUT",
  url: '../Server/test.php',
  data: {data:"data"}
});
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: '../Server/test.php',
  data: {data:"data"}
});
```

php:

```
<?
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
?>
```

in Chrome the response was PUT, PUT, GET
in Opera as expected POST, PUT, GET